# Laravel artisan command line

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, command-line-interface

I am using Laravel 4.1 and the artisan tool to develop some cli scripts for our website.
These scripts will run in the background though cron jobs.

I have come across a bug/feature and was wondering if anyone else has run into this problem or knows how to overcome this.

Description:

In the start folder under artisan.php i have added my commands:

```
Artisan::add(new VinCommand);
Artisan::add(new DealersCommand);
Artisan::add(new ReportingCommand);
Artisan::add(new AutoInventoryCommand);
Artisan::add(new VastLeadsCommand);
Artisan::add(new SendInventoryAlertsCommand);
Artisan::add(new JumpstartCapCommand);
```

Under app -> commands i have all my commands.
In AutoInventoryCommand.php i am running a truncate table in the __construct method, but i am finding that the truncate is being called on every cli command.

For instance VinCommand:

```
php artisan command:vin_command
```

also runs AutoInventoryCommands __construct method, which is causing the table to always be truncated.

Is it common knowledge not to put any logic in the __construct method?

In some of the other commands i set private static variables in the __contruct method. Is this bad practice. Should i have an _init() method that gets called in:

```
public function fire()
{
    $this->_init();
}
```

And this will set my variables. I would have never have caught this if i didnt have an:

```
echo "Table Truncated \n";
```

in the truncate method.

So is this a bug/common knowledge

I assume this is happening because all the __constructs are called when the:

```
Artisan::add();
```

is called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course it is run on every command. You have `new AutoInventoryCommand` right there in your code!

If you insist on keeping your code in the constructor (which you shouldn't), you can register your commands with `resolve` instead:

```
Artisan::resolve('AutoInventoryCommand');
```